# jsPDF ignores empty <p> tags and spacing before text in <p>

Tags: php, jspdf

I´m using jsPDF to generate and download a PDF with user notes from a SQL result.

As i want line breaks, I´ve used the preg_split to later echo the result out in `<p>` tags.
But they get ignored by jsPDF.

```
$prenote = $row[$x]['body'];
$paragraphs = preg_split('/\n+/', $prenote);

foreach($paragraphs as $p){
    echo "<p>$p</p>";
}
```

The jsPDF part:

```
doc.fromHTML(responseFromAjax, margins.left, margins.top,{
    'width': margins.width // max width of content on PDF
}
```

**Problem is. instead of:**

Test note from user with many line breaks.

test line

test line

test line.

**The result is this:**

Test note from user with many line breaks.

test line

test line

test line.

Example of my ajaxresponse which is used for creating the pdf

```
                            <h4>Artikel 3</h4>
            <p>saasa  s3434</p><p>  cscx  xc  xc  cxcx</p><p>asd</p><p>   </p><p>asd</p><p>asd</p><p>asd</p><p>a</p><p>sd</p><p>asd</p>
```

Comment: Looks like you only output a `p` tag if there is content, I think you need an else in there `if(strlen.... } else { echo '<p>$nbsp;</p>';}`

Comment: @Dale Oh yes, I see that... Could have been that but even without the problem is still there. I´m removed the if part of the foreach

Comment: Maybe the empty `p` is collapsed by jsPDF? Try adding the if back and outputing a `<p>&nbsp;</p>` this should (hopefully) stop it being collapsed

Comment: @Dale Thanks! but that also gets ignored :(